# UIWebView Produces Blank White Screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am having trouble resolving an odd issue with my webView.  I am attempting to load a web page (any web page) in a webView which is the sole object within a UIViewController. When I create an instance of the view controller and push it onto the stack, the screen is blank and white.  For now I am attempting to load www.apple.com.  Here is the relevant code:

UIViewController:

```
import UIKit

class GoodReadsVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.apple.com")
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView?.loadRequest(requestObj);
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

For what it is worth, I know that the webView is indeed connected to the xib, due to the little dot being filled in the left margin.

Pushing the controller onto the nav stack:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let bookWebView = GoodReadsVC(nibName: "GoodReadsVC", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(bookWebView, animated: true)


        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your web view is visible and its frame is set on-screen?

Comment: I believe so.  I set constraints in the IB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a case of the loading being blocked by this error:

Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

The solution to this problem may be found here:

[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: for https:// url, am getting white screen before loading content for the very first time. any suggestions?